# Can anyone explain me what is better solution for creating an AlertDialog in the android app development?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

What is the better solution of creating an AlertDialog in the android app development:

1. Creating an AlertDialog with AlertDialog.Builder in the
   fragment(class extends 
      DialogFragment)
2. Creating an AlertDialog with AlertDialog.Builder without fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends,

By simplicity, I always create an standar AlertDialog like this:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
    } else {
       builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    }
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.message))
    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ready), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
         }
    })

.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
.setCancelable(true)
.show();
```

But you can `extend DialogFragment class` if you want to build more functions and capabilities within the dialog like adding a list and execute your custom click functions,

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Depends.

The simpler solution is the one without extending `DialogFragment`. I use it for simple dialogs where you have some text and two buttons (yes/no).

The `DialogFragment` variant is fully customizable and has all the abilities of a `Fragment`, especially using your own custom layout.

Comment: You can show `DialogFragment` and kill the app without memory leak. But You will get memory leak if You show the `AlertDialog` and kill the app,

Comment: @deadfish Citation needed. To my best knowledge, if you kill the app, there can be no memory leak, because the app will be completely removed from memory.